# Overvoltage protection for ESP32 (3v3)

Tags: esp32, switching-regulator, tvs, over-voltage-protection

I am trying to desing a switching regulator power supply for esp32 s3 (3v3). this is my schematic, I am using [PAM2310](https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/611744_237177.pdf) for switch regulator. I have tested it works fine. But sometimes I am thinking, Does this regulator leak too much voltage? In this case, won't it damage the esp32? I wonder what kind of protection measures should I take so that 3v3 doesn't get worse?

in some places i see people using TVS, is that possible to use [this TVS](https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/423535_5531176.pdf) at question marked on my schematic.

[image]

Comment: Why would it "leak" voltage, how would it do it? Sure, if for example the feedback resistor falls off, the output will be more than 3.3V and it will burn the ESP, so what scenarios you want to be protected against?

Comment: I don't have a specific scenario in mind, but I'm thinking about how to protect the esp32 if the pam2310 gives high voltage momentarily.

Comment: Yes but if you don't have a specific scenario in mind, why would PAM2310 output any overvoltage if there is no specific reason to do so?